# When is JQuery keydown event thrown?

Tags: jquery

I am using a third-party control (Aspose.Cells.GridWeb). It is basically a web based Excel control.  When a user selects a cell, the onCellSelected event is raised by the control.

The thing is, I need to know what key was pressed by the user to cause this event to be raised. I need this information to determine how to handle the event.

I am using JQuery's keydown event to capture the button clicked.

```
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        isKeyLastClicked = true;
        keyLastClickedId = event.which;
        isMouseButtonLastClicked = false;
        mouseButtonLastClickedId = null;
    });
```

The problem is that the control's onCellSelected event is raised BEFORE the keydown event is raised. Is this expected behavior?

Is there any way to get the id of the key before the control's event is raised?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After a long discussion at the SO chat...*
Since binding the `keydown` event does not produce the desired results, you have to alter the `onCellSelected` function. It should follow the next pattern:

1. When onCellSelected is triggered for the first time, the first argument (`cell`) is assigned to a (temporary) variable.
2. Then, when a `keydown` event occurs, the key code is checked:

   - If the pressed key (`ev.which` or `ev.keyCode`) equals a certain key, the `onCellSelected` function is called again, passing the value of the temporary variable as a first argument.
   - Else, the temporary variable is cleared, since it makes no sense to remember it.

The code would have the following structure. Modify it to suit your application:

```
var lastCell = null;
function onCellSelected (cell) {
    if(lastCell == null) {
        lastCell = cell;
        return; //Wait for the next listener
    }
    ... //Rest of code
}

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(lastCell == null) return; //No need to do unnecessary calculations
    //Whatever you want, example:
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        onCellSelected(lastCell);
        lastCell = null; //Reset
    }
    ... //Rest of code
});
```

Note: `keyCode`, `charCode` and `which`, see also: http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure as to how to get the `keydown` event to fire first (or if it even possible). But, I did discover that you can access the last windows event at any time. So instead of relying on the event to set the variables as shown in my original question above, I simply access `window.event.type`.

Here is some sample code:showing how to use `window.event`:

```
if (window.event.type == "keydown") { //keyboard click
    if (IsKeyNextType(window.event.which)) { //checks which key was pressed. In this case a key qualifying as "Next" (ie: Enter, Tab, etc)
            //PERFORM NEXT ACTIONS
    }
    else { //"Previous" keys (ie: Up arrow, Left arrow)
            //PERFORM PREVIOUS ACTIONS
    }
}
else if (window.event.type == "click") { //mouse click
    //PERFORM MOUSE CLICK ACTIONS
}
```

Comment: `window.event` is a non-standard IE-only feature.

Comment: @RobW: Are you sure? It works fine in Chrome. What are the equivalent events in other browsers?

Comment: The event object makes sense in the context of an event listener. When an event listener is triggered, the first argument of the function is the event object. `window.event` is at least not supported in Firefox.

Comment: @RobW: Is there any way to do the equivalent of `window.event.type` in  FF? If not then I am probably back to square one, where the `keydown` event is fired too late.

Comment: Welcome back to square one :/

Comment: @RobW: Argh :). Is what Neal stated in the other answer true? That the order matters? Would the event be fired any earlier or later depending on where I subscribe to it? Seems wrong to me. But willing to try anything.

Comment: Shai, can you pass a source to me, where your code is demonstrated? If not, try wrapping your event handler in `$(function(){...})`, and define this code **before** your 3rd-party code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4585/discussion-between-shai-cohen-and-rob-w)

Answer (score 0):

It add depends on the **order** of your code.

Which ever is first in the code will get executed first.

Also it is better to use callbacks instead of two separate functions (which could be volatile).